# word boundary and less than sign

Tags: python, regex

I want these 3 asserts to pass, what's wrong the the regular expression used?

The last assert fails.

```
import re

def line_has_word(line, word):
    expr = re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(word))
    return expr.search(line) is not None

assert line_has_word('foo', 'foo')
assert not line_has_word('zfoo', 'foo')
assert line_has_word('<foo', '<foo')
```

Comment: @anubhava, yes, but there is a `assert not`

Comment: ok got it. Try: `expr = re.compile(r'(^|\s)' + re.escape(word))`

Comment: @anubhava, works, thanks! (I'm still trying to understand your regex)

Comment: `(^|\s)` part means match line start or a whitespace before actual search word

Comment: Note that this will not match on `line_has_word('bar,foo', 'foo')` and will match on `line_has_word('fooled', 'foo')` - which might or might not be what you want to achieve.

Comment: What about `\W` (matches non-alphanumeric characters) instead of `\s`?

Answer (score 2):

`\b` matches to empty string at beginning or end of a word and word is defined as "sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters" which `<` is not part of. Here's the full description from [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, so the precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'. Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Translating my comment into an answer.

Problem is your use of `\b` (word boundary) before search term. **This will fail the assertion if first character of search term is a non-word character.**

You can instead use this negative lookbehind assertion:

```
>>> def line_has_word(line, word):
...     expr = re.compile(r'(?<!\w)' + re.escape(word))
...     return expr.search(line) is not None
...
```

`(?<!\w)` is negative lookbehind assertion which means previous position from search term doesn't have a word character.

**Testing:**

```
>>> print line_has_word('<foo', '<foo')
True
>>> print line_has_word('zfoo', 'foo')
False
>>> print line_has_word('bar,foo', 'foo')
True
>>> print line_has_word('foo', 'foo')
True
```